# Check if numbers in column counted correctly independent from a direct cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following simple Excel spreadsheet:

```
         A         B            C
1        1       
2        2       =IF(A2=A1+1;"ok";"error")
3        3       =IF(A3=A2+1;"ok";"error")
4        4       =IF(A4=A3+1;"ok";"error")
5        5       =IF(A5=A4+1;"ok";"error")
```

In column A I just entered numbers 1 to 5. The formula in Column B checks if the numbers always count correctly so it gives an error in case I type in cell A3 number 4 instead of 3 and so on.

However, when I delete row 3 completely I will get a `#REF!` in cell B4.

I want to make this system smart enough so it ignores the `#REF!` and continues its check which means that instead of `#REF!` in cell B4 a normal "error" appears because it does not count correctly anymore since it will go from 2 *(Cell A2)* to 4 *(Cell A4)*.

Do you have any ideas how I can make the formulas in column B independent from a direct reference to a cell in column A?

Comment: As an aside, if you really wanted to enforce that A contain sequential numbers no matter what, you could simply use `=ROW()` (and lock the values). (Of course, this may be a simplified example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reference those cells that may be deleted indirectly.
Paste the following into B2 and copy it to B3-B5 from there:

```
=IF(A2=INDIRECT("R"&ROW()-1&"C"&COLUMN()-1;FALSE)+1;"ok";"error")
```

In effect, you replace the direct relative reference

```
A1
```

By an indirect relative reference

```
INDIRECT("R"&ROW()-1&"C"&COLUMN()-1;FALSE)
```

You should be aware that the strings "R" and "C" may differ for non-English Excel versions as those could use different words for "Row" and "Column". As German uses "Zeile" and "Spalte", for instance, in a German Excel version you'd have to type

```
INDIREKT("Z"&ZEILE()-1&"S"&SPALTE()-1,FALSCH)
```